# windowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT | Android

Tags: android, xml

Приветы!

Уже долго мучаюсь вопросом и гугл ответа не дает...

Кусок кода:

```
mViewMain = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

mLayoutParamsForMain = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                                 mFlagsForMain,
                                 PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

mWindowManager.addView(mViewMain, mLayoutParamsForMain);
```

Все это происходит в `Service`.
Я адаптирую разметку xml чисто в ландшафтном ориентации и под планшеты с большим экраном. 
В пример возьму эмулятор Nexus 10 с экраном 2560x1600 xhdpi.
все размеры выставляю в: `res/values-w820dp/dimens.xml`
Приставки `-land` нигде не использую, так как пока не вижу в этом смысла.

Далее сама разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_test"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_test_width" <!--580dp-->
        android:layout_height="@dimen/main_test_height"> <!--wrap_content-->

    </LineareLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Здесь у меня ширина `main_test` равна 580dp, в `LayoutParams` = `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Теперь вопрос: пытаясь сделать ширину **БОЛЬШЕ** 580dp — результата 0 (как было так и осталось). Как убрать эти отступы в ландшафте, что за это отвечает **?**

П.с. выставление `MATCH_PARENT` в `LayoutParams` с дальнейшими `margin`ами в xml меня не устраивает, так как заполняя всю ширину, этот layout будет лишен возможности передвижения по ширине — `OnTouchListener`, хотя и решает эту проблему полностью. Так же решает и выставление `LayoutParams` в `px`, но опять же — интересует, почему при `WRAP_CONTENT` нельзя увеличить ширину и остаются отступы **?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока вопрос решается так:

```
int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.main_width), getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

mLayoutParamsMain = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                                 mFlagsForMain,
                                 PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

И:

```
res/values/integers.xml <-- main_width
```

Для планшетов:

```
res/values-w820dp/integers.xml <-- main_width
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrap_content` - размер, рассчитанный из необходимого для отображения контента места и не более, чем для этого требуется. Вы не можете напрямую влиять на этот параметр, не переопределив собственный класс (и расчет этого параметра в нем).

Для того, чтобы визуально расширить виджет с параметром `wrap_content`, вы можете указывать паддинги (padding) - отступы внутри виджета, от границы виджета до его контента.